# Iterate and validate DOM Nodes - java

Tags: java, validation, dom

I want to iterate through all child nodes in XML file. If validation of value fails then I want to append/clone node to a new xml document. Any suggestions to the below code?

```
for(Node childNode = node.getFirstChild(); childNode!=null;)
{
   Node nextChild = childNode.getNextSibling();
   //validate here and append or
   //clone to new xml file if false
   childNode = nextChild;
}
```

I created the validator instance and it does validate each node. how do I find out what node fails(true, false) and then append. Can I use boolean value for failed validation and then append to new document?

```
// creating a Validator instance 
Validator validator = schema.newValidator(); 
Validator.validate(new DOMSource(childNode)) ;
```

Comment: I created the validator instance and it does validate each node. how
do I find out what node fails(true, false) and then append. Can I use boolean value for failed validation and then append to new document? 

    // creating a Validator instance
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    Validator.validate(new DOMSource(childNode)) ;

Comment: Please update your question by clicking the "edit" button and including the information in your comment so that others can easily see it.  You'll get better responses this way =)